# Select latest in each subgroup for each joined row

Tags: mysql, join, group-by

I have two tables: *sessions* and *session_states*. First table has some general info about session.

Second table contains state history for each session; multiple rows may be connected to the same session (column *session_id*); row with latest *timestamp* represents current/actual state for a given session.

*sessions*

```
id   search_criteria   some_other_info
1    aaa               something
2    bbb               something
3    aaa               something
```

*session_states*

```
pk   session_id   state   timestamp
1    1            new     01/01/1970 00:01
2    1            active  01/01/1970 00:02
3    2            new     01/01/1970 01:01
4    3            new     01/01/1970 02:01
```

I'm trying to create a query that allow to sort by column *search_criteria* and represent a list of matched session with their **current** states. Something like this (WHERE search_criteria = 'aaa'):

```
id   search_criteria   some_other_info   state   timestamp
1    aaa               something         active  01/01/1970 00:02
3    aaa               something         new     01/01/1970 02:01
```

My query:

```
SELECT s.id, s.search_criteria, s.some_other_info, st.state, st.timestamp
FROM sessions s
    JOIN
    (SELECT session_id, state, MAX(timestamp) FROM session_states GROUP BY session_id DESC) st
    ON s.id = st.session_id
WHERE search_criteria = 'aaa';
```

When there are 400k+ rows in each table, query takes 1+ seconds to execute. Query analyzer says that in right part of JOIN we loop through each row.

Any way to do this in more effective way?

P.S. I'm able to use only MySQL 5.6 / 5.7.

Comment: Generally, the columns in the GROUP BY are the non-aggregated columns in the SELECT. For further help, (and in the first instance) see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Also queries against VIEWs in MySQL have limited access to underlying indexes, rendering them (in my view) almost pointless

Comment: Your subquery does not return the column `session_id` so you can't join on that. Post your actual code.